# Problems with the bot discord Moderation

Tags: discord.py

I created a lot of moderation teams, ban, kick muta, etc. I tried to do such a thing: If a person enters a command (for example, ban) and does not enter arguments (participant name and reason), the bot gives the corresponding message that there are not enough arguments  and which one. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MissingRequiredArgument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=argument#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument) is called whenever a parameter that is required, is not encountered. You can use this exception to send a message in chat whenever a required argument is missing.

MissingRequiredArgument also has a parameter of its own, which details the argument that is missing.

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

That's simple to implement. Here is the snippet of code to give you an idea.

```
async def test(ctx,name = None,reason = None):
    if name == None or reason == None:
        await ctx.send('Provide the Name and Reason')
    else:
        #PROCEEED HERE
        pass
```